# UIButton can not show until i click her super view

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, uibutton

```
UIButton *submitBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

submitBtn.frame=CGRectMake(48, 145, 62, 24);

[submitBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images/public/submit.png"] forState:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[submitBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[submitBtn setNeedsDisplay];

[self addSubview:submitBtn];
```

i have create view A and the add a view B in the view A ,the view B have a submitbtn UIbutton !

why this submitbtn button can not show !!
but i click his super view ,it can show again!

Comment: are b and a subclass of UIVIew? how are you adding b to a?

Answer (score 0):

Add This Btn on Super View

```
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:object_Btn];
```

try this